# background image is not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

So, I have two files one is for html and the other one is for CSS 
I made the connection between them like this:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login.css">
```

here is my html code, i just started so there is'n much code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login.css">

</head>
<body >
    <form>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and here is the css file

```
body
{
    background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg");

}
```

the problem is the background-image is not working

Comment: Can you check console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: your body is empty :/

Comment: There can be many possible reason for not having image displayed. Can you upload your folder somewhere and then give me the link so than i can see your html folder layout and see if you correctly giving the links of images and css file.

Comment: @SachinNambiar Right click on the page >> inspect elements >> console 
if this is how i open the console, i think  I have no errors it shows me nothing

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 
i have a folder inside that folder i have the html file and two other folders one is called CSS inside it i have a login.css file and the other folder called Images and inside it i have an image called header.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe

Please let us know the folder structure or the print screen of the same.
and also let us know is it the localhost or its the server.
It might be because of case you have CSS in capital letter which should be smallcase.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
```

Comment: i have a folder inside that folder i have the html file and two other folders one is called CSS inside it i have a login.css file and the other folder called Images and inside it i have an image called header.jpeg

Comment: can you add printscreen ?

Comment: the html file and the style file is connected correctly , i tried to make other styles like background-color and it worked, but when ever i try background-image it does not work, i also tried to make the style inline in the html file but still the same

Comment: no i can't i don't have enough "reputation" on this website, but if you want give me your email and i can send you everything there.

Comment: I have made a reply on your email please check :)

Comment: can you try it with other Image ?

Comment: Dude problem solved it jpg not jpeg :) lol 
in css make it 

body
{
    background-image:url("../Images/header.jpg");

}

Instead of 

body
{
    background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg");
}

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7   set it in your PC

Answer (score 0):

Well it's because you don't have contents inside your `body`.

You can either:

**Add content to body** (Like obviously you would - but incase the issue is on other elements same logic applied)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login.css">
</head>
<body >
    <form>
    <div>
      Background Show
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Or Add `height` and `width` using `css`**

```
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: still the same dude, white page with controls !

Comment: @S.Joe Ok, can you make sure you set the correct location of your background image being set here: `background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg");`. You can easily check that by using [console tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

Comment: @S.Joe Upon seeing your recent comment above, it seems you're not seeing any errors on your console tab. What I suggest to debug is you add `!important` to your `css` probably there's an existing `style` being prioritized. E.g. `body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg") !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your body element doesn't have a width or a height.

try this:

```
body
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url("../Images/header.jpeg");
}
```

Of course you don't have to give the body a fixed width and height. Just make sure that there is some content in it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add something between the blank divs your background picture should show.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfsqups2/1/)**

```
html
{
    background:url("http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/748777_orig.jpg") no-repeat 100% 100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Specify `height as 100%` for `html, body` along with `background size:100%`